# Display Map Markers from Lat Lon

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers, latitude-longitude, google-latitude

I am learning android. Right now I am working on an app that uses map api. So far I did the following: 
- I long clicked the map and opened a new activityClickedMap displaying lat and lon of the location I clicked
- I clicked save button and added lat and lon, both to server and to my local db

The thing I want to do is this:
- When I open the map I want it to display a marker using the lat and the lon from database

Comment: Please post your code whatever you tried.

Comment: just get the lat and long from DB and store them in list under ** public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {}** with loop to display every marked  place  if you are using google maps or else post your code to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve  lat and long from database.

```
String  latfromdb , longfromdb ;
```

and then

`LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latfromdb),Double.parseDouble(longfromdb))`;

```
 MarkerOptions optionss = new MarkerOptions()
                    .alpha(1)
                    .flat(false)
                    .position(latLng)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin));
            googleMap.addMarker(optionss);
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
```

Get the list of lat long from db and Add Marker in for loop for multiple marker :

```
MarkerOptions optionss = new MarkerOptions()
                    .alpha(1)
                    .flat(false)
                    .position(latLng)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin));
            googleMap.addMarker(optionss);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker?hl=en
```

So the thing is - you get coords from db and put them all to your map.